# How to stop an ENTRYPOINT in a docker container from digesting errors from a script that is executed by a CMD step?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, datadog

I have a Dockerfile that has an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` step. So far, there were errors in the script and those were returned correctly with an exit code of 1. However, the container was somehow digesting those errors such that the Cloud Run Job was always marked as successful.

In the logs of that cloud run job, there were ERROR severity logs but the job was still successful. It was only when I had to comment out the ENTRYPOINT that the container exited with 1, and after 3 retries, the job was marked as failed.

```
COPY --from=datadog/serverless-init:1 /datadog-init /app/datadog-init
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/datadog-init"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/groot_migrator.sh"]
```

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/google_cloud_run/) and cannot figure out how to set some config such that errors are not swallowed.

The datadog-init, as in the hyperlinked documentation, is used here to instrument the application.

> The serverless-init application wraps your process and executes it as a subprocess. It starts a DogStatsD listener for metrics and a Trace Agent listener for traces. It collects logs by wrapping the stdout/stderr streams of your application. After bootstrapping, serverless-init then launches your command as a subprocess.

The overall picture is to run a CloudRun job that has a shell script (as in the CMD step), that further runs a rust code and I verified, the rust code is propagated correctly to the shell script, which further propagates any failure in a correct manner.

Comment: A container only runs a single process, with the `CMD` passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.  Can you [edit] the question to include a little more detail about what's going on?  What does the `datadog-init` wrapper do; do you have its source code?

Comment: ...this could be a bug in `serverless-init`; see [DataDog/datadog-agent#21879](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/21879).  If the `ENTRYPOINT` returns status code 0 regardless of what processes it spawns do, there's nothing Docker can do to correct that.